# strptime() argument 1 must be str, not DeferredAttribute

Tags: django, datetime

I am heaving trouble here, am making a travel and visa website, am trying to make sure we know each appointment 10 days in advance.
So I made a model property that would help me compare dates, but am having trouble error after error
here is the model field

```
class customer(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
biometry_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default='', null=True)


@property
def is_due(self):
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(Profile.biometry_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    t2 = datetime.now().date()
    t3 = timedelta(days=30)
    return  datetime_object - t2<= t3
```

and in the Html template

```
{% if customer.is_due %}
<td class="text-right">
<span class="badge badge-danger">{{ profile.biometry_date }}</span>
</td>
{% else %}
<td>{{ customer.biometry_date }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: `datetime_object = self.biometry_date`

Answer (score 0):

Firstfully, as Willem pointed - you don't need to use `strptime` from field, it's already `datetime.datetime` object. And you should use `self` when you want to use the object's field values. So:

```
def is_due(self):
    datetime_object = self.biometry_date
```

Secondly, I think you try to use interchangeably `profile` and `customer`. Decide which you are going to use or at least share the context.

Comment: Its customer model, well thanks for the answers, when I collected the line, now its switched to an other errors which I was trying to fix but failed which is '''TypeError at /dashboard/customers/
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.date''''

Comment: @user19686784 that means that your object has empty value of `biometry_date` field and it cannot process that line: `datetime_object - t2<= t3`.

Comment: of course, some users will have that empty field empty, is there a way you can engineer that conditionally, depending on whether the user has filled it or not? and check that in the template, I don't know if one would still use a model property. any guidance will help

Comment: Just put everything after first line `datetime_object = ...` into `if datetime_object:` or something like that.

Comment: @user19686784 no problem. Tick Answer as correct if helped. Good luck!